# What would be a correct way of implementing a <br> here? Also, why is the square the wrong color?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, here is the code I'm working with.

```
<html>
<head>

    <script>
        onload=function
        main()
        {
            function createSquare(type)
            {
                let square = document.createElement("div");
                square.style.width = "50px";
                square.style.height = "50px";
                square.style.display = "inline-block";
                if(type == "blue")
                {
                    square.style.backgroundColor = "#00f";
                }
                else if(type == "red")
                {
                    square.style.backgroundColor = "#f00";
                }
                else if(type="blueEnd")
                {
                    square.style.backgroundColor = "#00f";
                    square.innerHTML = "<br>"
                }
                else if(type="redEnd")
                {
                    square.style.backgroundColor = "#f00";
                    square.innerHTML = "<br>"
                }
                document.body.appendChild(square);
            }
            createSquare("blue");
            createSquare("redEnd");
            createSquare("red");
            createSquare("redEnd");
        };
    </script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

It produces an unexpected result, where it just moves the square down. Also, the "redEnd" is blue for some reason, when I've set it to be `backgroundColor = "#f00";`.

I can see that I just did something wrong, and there will be some nice function to make the <br> work, but what *really* confuses me is that wrong color on "redEnd".

I feel like I wan’t clear on what I want, so I’m editing it now. When I give “redEnd” argument, I want to draw the square, then move to the next line.

Comment: Why are you putting a line break in a div with no other content? There's no line of text to break.

Comment: Idk man I’m just trying to get the squares to be on different lines

Comment: Why are you using `display: inline-block` if you want them on different lines? `inline-block` is explicitly for putting blocks **on the same line**! And if you want the *squares* on different lines, why put the line break **inside** them?

Comment: Oh my god, how did I not realize this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have used `=` for comparing `redEnd` and `blueEnd`. Use `===` for comparisons and then try